# Need user input data converted as percentage and added to a total sum variable Python 3.6

Tags: python, variables, percentage, python-3.6

How do you convert user input data collected as an integer into a percentage and then have that converted percentage data into a running sum total stored in a variable? I need the "Tax percentage to be collected" input data converted into a percent and somehow added to the "t" variable.

Here is how I am collecting the data:

```
b = 0
b += int(input("Acquisition cost?"))
b += int(input("Misc Expenses?"))

t = 0
t += int(input("Processing fee"))
t += int(input("Tax percentage to be collected"))

s = 0
s += int(input("Sell price?"))


net_profit =  (b + t) - s
cost_to_buyer = s + t
```

Again, I need the "Tax percentage to be collected" input question data that is collected as an integer converted to a percent and added to the running total "t" variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like :

```
t *= 1+int(input("Tax percentage to be collected"))/100
```

---

Example

```
t = 0
t += int(input("Processing fee")) # input 100
t *= 1+int(input("Tax percentage to be collected"))/100 # input 5

print(t) # result 105.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'd start out by making the code more readable:

```
acquisition_cost = int(input("Acquisition cost?"))
expenses = int(input("Misc Expenses?"))

total_cost = acquisition_cost + expenses 


tax = int(input("Processing fee"))
# Is this what you were looking for? 
tax_band = float(input("Tax percentage to be collected"))/100

total_tax = tax * tax_band


sell_price = int(input("Sell price?"))

net_profit = (total_cost + total_tax) - sell_price
cost_to_buyer = sell_price + total_tax
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
t = 0
t += int(input("Processing fee"))
t += t / 100 * int(input("Tax percentage to be collected"))
```

? I'm not sure if I fully understand your question.

Comment: i hope your tax are not based on this code :p .. i think you're just dividing  the wrong number --> `int(input("Tax percentage to be collected"))/100`

Comment: haha, damn, yes of course. time to go to bed. I fixed the code in my answer, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Haha thank you for the info. What actually fixed my code was: t *= float(input("Tax percentage to be collected"))/100

Comment: If you mean that you needed `t *= 1 + float(input("Tax percentage to be collected"))/100` as in the accepted answer, then mine is actually mathematically identical :-)